# Coordinates export in Zest

Tags: java, layout, graph, zest

Is there any way of getting coordinates of layout (nodes, lines, bendpoints) of graphs in Zest (Eclipse)?
I tried several approaches, with Draw2D which comes in package with Zest, but I don't know how to make Zest object an instance of Draw2D graph.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code in these files:

```
org.eclipse.zest.layouts/src/org/eclipse/zest/layouts/exampleUses/SimpleSwingExample.java

org.eclipse.zest.layouts/src/org/eclipse/zest/layouts/exampleUses/SimpleSWTExample.java
```